# Change data-src to src via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider, custom-data-attribute

Im using a flexslider that has audio files for each slide, but I don't want to load countless audio files right away on the page.  So im trying to get the data-src to become the src after each slide

the slides are currently as follows:

```
<div class="flexslider carousel">
<ul class="slides">
<li> 
<img src="http://www.quinnmedical.com/skin/frontend/gigasavvy/quinn/ppt/Slide01.jpg"  /> 
<audio id="demo" controls>
   <source src="/skin/frontend/gigasavvy/quinn/audio/Slide1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
</li>
<li> 
<img src="http://www.quinnmedical.com/skin/frontend/gigasavvy/quinn/ppt/Slide03.jpg"  /> 
<audio id="demo" controls>
   <source data-src="/skin/frontend/gigasavvy/quinn/audio/Slide3.mp3" src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In the after function i want to change data-src to src.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as how to go from data-src to src

Comment: You can't change it. All you can do is add a new attribute and remove a previous one.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to set < audio preload="none">, which will just turn off all preloading of files. Or if you really want preload of the current slide, change the preload property to "auto" when the slide is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming an attribute is not be possible. You can add new attribute and remove the old one.

Suppose there is a click event as in the following example:

```js
$('#demo').on("click", "img", function () {
   var t = this;
   var source = $(t).children("source");        
   $source.attr({
       src: $t.attr('data-src')
   }).removeAttr('data-src');
}
```

Please modify the event according to your requirements.

Comment: thank you very much, that saved the day.  I have 37 slides with audio files and that keeps the page going.  Thank you again @dvk317960

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('source').attr("src", $(this).data('src'));
$('source').removeAttr('data-src');
```

This should move the url from `data-src` to `src`, and then remove the `data-src` attribute.

Comment: it's : $('source').attr("src", $(this).data('data-src'));

Answer (score 0):

Inside the after function get the currently visible slide and then get the auto on it and it's source. Next check to see if it already has a `src` attribute. If not then set it to it's own `.data('src')`. Add this into the flexslider object.

```
after: function(){
    var $currentAudio = $('.flex-active-slide audio source');
    if(!$currentAudio.attr('src')){
        $currentAudio.attr('src', $currentAudio.data('src'));
    }
}
```